# convergence of a real sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

Consider a real sequence $(x_k)$ for $k=0,1,2,\dots$ as $x_0=1$ and for $k>0$
$$ x_k=x_{k-1}+\frac{\gamma}{k}x_{k-1}^2,\qquad (\gamma>0).$$
I wonder to show that the sequence is bounded (thus convergent). I appreciate any idea for proving that.

Hint: Numerical experiments suggest me that if and only if $\gamma<1$ the sequence is bounded.

Comment: Is your $\gamma>0$ ?

Comment: yes! I forgot to mention that. I will edit the question

Comment: Note that $x_k\geqslant1$ for every $k\geqslant0$, hence $x_k\geqslant x_{k-1}+\frac{\gamma}k$ for every $k\geqslant1$ hence $x_k\geqslant1+\gamma\sum\limits_{i=1}^k\frac1i$ for every $k\geqslant1$, in particular, $x_k\to\infty$ when $k\to\infty$ (for every $\gamma>0$).

Comment: Which begs the question -- what are the numerical experiments? They should show divergence even by eyeballing,  since the rate is at least logarithmic.

Comment: @Did Thank you! I refer you to my reply to Umberto P.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\gamma > 0$ you have that $\{x_k\}$ is increasing and in particular $x_k \ge 1$ for all $k$.  Since $$x_k - x_{k-1} = \frac{\gamma}{k} x_{k-1}^2$$ you get $$x_{n} - x_0 = \sum_{k=1}^n (x_k - x_{k-1}) = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\gamma}k x_{k-1}^2 \ge \gamma \sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1k.$$
That is,
$$x_n \ge 1 + \gamma \sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1k$$ so that the sequence is unbounded as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: You are right! thank you. The point was that after seeing your answer I found out that I had a mistake in the sequence; there is a difference between my numerical experiments and the sequence I have here. What I really want is not the current form but the other one. I think about it again and if I fail I ask it here again. Thank you for your reply anyway. @Umberto P.